# How to Load My Non-Public Site via HTTP (No SSL Config) - All Browsers Auto-Redirect to HTTPS

Tags: ssl, wordpress, redirect, hosts-file

I need to load my website via HTTP, but all browsers automatically redirect to HTTPS. I have no SSL setup on the site (the domain name is not registered anywhere), nor is the server expecting SSL (AFAIK).

I also run into this when I register a new domain name or make DNS changes for a site and set the IP in my hosts file before the DNS records can propagate, but this is usually resolved within an hour or two.

I manually added a development domain to my servers (not registered anywhere) and manually added the domain to my hosts file.

```
123.456.789.1    example.dev
```

I never setup SSL or HTTPS on the server for the domain, but Chrome/Edge/Firefox refuses to load the site over HTTP.

It is a WordPress installation, and I have the URL set to `http://example.dev`.

```
option_id | option_name | option_value       | autoload
1         | siteurl     | http://example.dev | 1
```

I tried deleting the HSTS settings on the domain in the browser via `(chrome|chromium|edge)://net-internals/#hsts`.

I set up a 301 to HTTP from HTTPS in the .htaccess file on the site, and a couple other things that escape my memory at this time.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Still, no luck. What else can I do to force HTTP on my non-public site?

EDIT:
It seems as though Chrome now requires all *.dev to have HSTS and HTTPS. I have since begun using a *.test domain name, and my issues are resolved.

Comment: This isn't a security question.  You would probably be better off asking it on serverfault.  In an attempt to give a general suggestion though, the first thing to do is to always isolate.  Instead of loading up in a browser, use something like `curl` or postman so you can view the full response headers/body from your server.  If the site itself is redirecting to https for some reason it will be obvious.  If you've never enabled HSTS then there is no reason why the browser would attempt to automatically redirect to https, so I suspect you have something misconfigured on the server.

Comment: Several dupes and crossdupes, mostly from 2017, linked at https://superuser.com/questions/1349836/fake-dev-domain-added-to-hosts-file-for-development-purposes-redirects-to-https

Answer (score 1):

HSTS is forced on .dev domains by the browsers.
You will have to use a different domain or set up HTTPS for your web server.

https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Comment: Wow! I had no idea HSTS was forced on *.dev sites.

In the meantime, how should I go about setting up SSL? The domain is not registered anywhere, so I cannot go through the normal channels for creating one.

Comment: You'd set it up with a self-signed certificate and then either add it to the trusted certs of your operating system or add an exception for it in your browser.
https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/